# Performing a manual sort on an Array

Tags: arrays, sorting

I'm using OpusScript, which is very similar to Javascript.

I need to sort an Array by two properties of the objects within it.

The object type of the array is 'ScoreEntity', with the properties Score and Time. I need the highest score at the 0 index of the array and vise versa, with the faster time overriding matching scores.

I've been trying to do this for ages and I cant get my head around it, I've got Saturday Syndrome!

**ANSWER:**

I used BubbleSort in the end, any comments on improving this are welcome.

```
function SortScoreArray(array)
{

    var unsorted = true
    while (unsorted)
    {

        // Tracks whether any changes were made, changed to false on any swap
        var complete = true
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
        {           

            // Holds the value for determining whether to swap the current positions
            var swap = false

            var currentItem = array[i]
            var nextItem = array[i + 1]

            if (currentItem.Score == nextItem.Score)
            {

                // The scores are the same, so sort by the time
                if (currentItem.Time > nextItem.Time)
                {
                    swap = true
                }

            }
            else if (currentItem.Score < nextItem.Score)
            {
                swap = true
            }


            if (swap)
            {
                array[i] = nextItem
                array[i + 1] = currentItem
                complete = false
            }

        }

        if (complete)
        {
            unsorted = false
        }

    }

    return array

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you choose an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)? (QuickSort is nice)

You have to define a comparison function determining which `ScoreEntity` is less (by comparing score and time) and then just implement the algorithm.

(I don't know OpusScript - Maybe you can just use a builtin sort which you tell the comparsion predicate)

Comment: No built in sort unfortunately. I'm aware of what I have to do, I just cant seem to write the logic down!

Comment: Ah, sorry just found the actual QuickSort article, I'll try and convert the psuedo code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used BubbleSort in the end.